Not able to access pemisison set
I am System Administrator in my dev sandbox.
I search for my permission set in setup and want to open the permission set.
When I click on the permission set name in search result, I get below error:

I have verified that System Administrator profile have Manage Profile and Permission Sets is enable for the System Administrator profile:

What could be the issue here?

A couple of possibilities. Have you confirmed that you are in fact set up with the System Administrator profile? Also, is this Permission Set from a Managed Package?

Found a thing. That is actually Permission Set group. But When I search in setup and try to open, I get error. I went to Permission Set Groups via Quick Find and able to open the permisison set group.
